# Emacs displays raw text instead of unicode

Tags: character-encoding

I'm working on a LaTeX document in emacs (27.1) that contains english as well as sanskrit (devanagari) text. After running aspell on the document, I ran `M-x revert-buffer` and attempted to save the document, when emacs popped a warning window that said something like "These bytes cannot be written". I may have ignored the warning and written the file in `raw-text-unix` format. Now when I open the file, I see a bunch of numbers. E.g

[image: How text appears in emacs]

I selected the entire text in this file and ran `M-x recode-region`

```
Text was really in: utf-8
But was interpreted as: raw-text-unix
```

After this, emacs displays unicode (devanagari) text as expected but these changes do not persist. Whenever I relaunch emacs and open this file, I just see bytes (and not unicode characters). How do I fix this?

EDIT:
The `file` command shows the the current file has a non-iso extended-ascii text. This is different from my other latex files. E.g:

```
✗ file naishadham-chap4.tex # doc with problem
naishadham-chap4.tex: LaTeX document text, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators
✗ file naishadham-chap3.tex
naishadham-chap3.tex: LaTeX document text, UTF-8 Unicode text
```